jstest-gtk and wrong mapping of axes
Was following an online tutorial and noticed that when I ran jstest-gtk into terminal the right joystick on my PS4 controller wasn't map correctly and was limited to up or down (left for up and right for down). Additionally I noticed that L2 trigger was capable of moving the axes horizontally to the right. How can I fix this?
I've included a screenshot (note that I am not touching the controller).


You might be better off using evdev.
Note that /dev/input/js is deprecated and you should use /dev/input/event instead. From Problem with emulator and joystick mapping

Okay. So, there is a bit of a confusing dichotomy when it comes to joysticks in Linux. Every joystick gets two device nodes: /dev/input/eventXX, and /dev/input/jsXX. jsXX is vintage. Old. Deprecated. The only thing that uses it anymore is Wine*, pretty much, and I can't imagine that will last long either. Also SDL1.2 games, but if they haven't been ported to SDL2 yet, there are other problems. Everything uses the eventXX devices, including mupen64plus.
So why does this matter? Because the nifty JSTest-gtk calibration and remapping tool... only works on jsXX devices. You can't calibrate or remap eventXX devices (nearly as conveniently, anyways).
If you're using a frontend for mupen64plus, you should be configuring the pad in that frontend anyways. I can't imagine it wouldn't expose options to do so.
In any case, the fact that JSTest still exists and there are people out there still recommending it is a problem because it creates confusing situations like these. Once jsXX devices go away and JSTest disappears from the repos, it'll be less confusing for everyone.
*Even more confusing with Wine is that it uses both eventXX and jsXX devices, which means one device generates events for two controllers. More reason for jsXX to go away.

With respect to evdev : jstest-gtk is outdated and should not be used #2

Sadly, there are no good calibration tools for new subsystem besides using evdev-joystick with evdev, which require some skills.
...
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/evdev-joystick.1.html

From Gamepad

Linux has two different input systems for gamepads – the original Joystick interface and the newer evdev-based interface.
/dev/input/jsX maps to the Joystick API interface and /dev/input/event* maps to the evdev ones (this also includes other input devices such as mice and keyboards). Symbolic links to those devices are also available in /dev/input/by-id/ and /dev/input/by-path/ where the legacy Joystick API has names ending with -joystick while the evdev have names ending with -event-joystick.
Most new games will default to the evdev interface as it gives more detailed information about the buttons and axes available and also adds support for force feedback.

